# How to do has_many and has_one between the same tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, schema.rb

I have a table Contacts and a table Entities. One Entity can have many Contacts, while the samee Entity should store one peculiar Contact as a supervisor.

I couldn't find any straight answer elsewhere, but have something like this:

```
class Entity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contacts
  belongs_to :entity_contact, class_name: 'Contact', foreign_key: :contact_id, optional: true
end
```

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :entity
end
```

```
class CreateEntities < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :entities do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :organization, foreign_key: true
----> t.references :entity_contact

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

How can I achieve it and have something like Entity.first.entity_contact from ActiveRecord?

Many thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

I took some liberties with the naming for clarity:

```
class Entity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contacts
  belongs_to :supervisor, class_name: 'Contact', optional: true
end
```

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :entity
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: 'Entity', foreign_key: :supervisor_id
end
```

```
class CreateEntities < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :entities do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :organization, foreign_key: true
      t.references :supervisor, foreign_key: { to_table: :contacts }
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Got this error after many tries: "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "supervisor" does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

As your code and request above, just assign entity_contact to Contact model:

1. Add entity_contact_id column into existing contacts table:
   `$ rails generate migration AddEntityContactToEntity entity_contact_id:integer`

   Adjust migration file like:

```
class AddEntityContactToEntity < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :entities, :entity_contact, references: :contacts, index: { algorithm: :concurrently }, foreign_key: { to_table: :contacts }
  end
end
```

Run migrate:

`$ rails db:migrate`

2. Modify models:

```
class Entity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contacts
  belongs_to :entity_contact, class_name: :Contact, foreign_key: :entity_contact_id, optional: true
end
```

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :entities
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: :Entity, foreign_key: :entity_contact_id
end
```